# How do i style child ID base parant's class

Tags: html, css

I don't know if i am explaining it in right but i have a div with a certain class.
Inside the div I have a ul with an id - I am trying to style that ul.

This will demonstrate it better:

```
<div class="parent">
     <ul id="child">
          <li>
          </li>
     </ul>
</div>

<style type="text/css" media="screen">
.parent #child li{float:left;}
.parent #child{margin-bottom:54px;}
</style>
```

The above will not work i cant find the correct way of doing so. i tried `.parent > #child` and its still doesnt work.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: If it has an ID, it should be unique, so there is no point using an additional selector(`.parent`). However, the code should work, there is nothing wrong with it, what isn't working? The code says to float the list items left (so its a horizontal navigation) and to add a 54pixel margin to the bottom of the `ul` (though this won't be visible, as `ul`'s dont react well to widths, margins etc

Comment: yea i know the ID is Unique however i use that same div on several different page and i want it to look different on each page that is why i added the div . so that ul with id child under div class parent will be style in a certain way while others be style in another way. i hope that makes sense

Comment: Do you have your style tag in the HEAD of your page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now define your **child** `overflow:hidden`

as like this

```
.parent #child{overflow:hidden;}
```

***[Live Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/rLhd86tr)***

Comment: weird that it doesn't work for me .. in my site. extremely weird - and its not like there is any other element with that same id.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `ul#child` in your css for this. Basically what it does it checks your UL's for that id. I dont think the parents should matter cause you ll use an ID only once. if you want it to be used more, then make it a class.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle showing this working with a couple of css tweaks: http://jsfiddle.net/4RJKk/

Follow this code and you should be golden.

```
.parent {
    overflow:auto;
}
.parent #child li {
    float:left;
}
.parent #child{
    margin-bottom:54px;
}


<div class="parent">
     <ul id="child">
          <li>test</li>
          <li>test</li>
     </ul>
</div>

here
```